# How to move a shape and edit the vertices afterwards in threejs

Tags: javascript, three.js

thanks in advance for your help!! I've been depraved from sleeping with a problem with shapes created with the mouse using THREE.Shape, I have no problems drawing the shape and also editing the shape if it's on the center of the canvas (seems to be a local coordinates problem)
So here's how it works. Point is taken from the THREE.Raycaster

```
//Point is the vector3 returned by the Raycaster
ld.ui = 1;
const shapeVisible = new THREE.Shape();
shapeVisible.moveTo( point.x, point.y, ld.ui );
shapeVisible.lineTo( point.x, point.y, ld.ui );
const area = new THREE.ShapeGeometry(handle.shapeVisible);


//This is to move a the vertex
area.geometry.attributes.position.setXYZ( 0, point.x, point.y, ld.ui );
area.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
```

So far everything works whenever the shape is in the center, the farther the shape from the center the greater the shift in the vertex placement same when I try to move it like so:

```
//again pos is returned by the Raycaster, so it's should be moving it to the mouse position.
area.position.y = pos.y;
area.position.x = pos.x;
```

Now here is the problem, once I move the shape, it jumps like if it's origin is in a different place and when trying to edit again a vertex its extremely displaced

[image]

**Here is a simple fiddle to demonstrate the problem:** 
You can see here how anytime you try to move the green box it will jump to the mouse position but with the bottom left corner on the mouse instead of the center of the object.
https://jsfiddle.net/ox4q89fs/26/

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('#test');
const cons = document.querySelector('#console')
const mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
const raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  canvas: canvas,
  alpha: true,
  antialias: true
});
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
camera.position.z = 5;

const scene = new THREE.Scene();

const geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(20, 20);
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: 0x333333
});
const backplane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
const amblight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff);

scene.add(amblight);
scene.add(backplane);

//Drawing the shape, normally this is done with the mouse position
const shape = new THREE.Shape();
shape.moveTo(1, 1, 1);
shape.lineTo(1, 0, 1);
shape.lineTo(0, 0, 1);
shape.lineTo(0, 1, 1);
shape.lineTo(1, 1, 1);

const shapeGeo = new THREE.ShapeGeometry(shape);
const shapeMat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: 0x33ff33
});
const shapeMesh = new THREE.Mesh(shapeGeo, shapeMat)

scene.add(shapeMesh);

renderer.render(scene, camera);

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
animate()

function onWindowResize() {
  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}

function mouseController(event, type) {
  event.preventDefault();
  mouse.x = (event.layerX / canvas.width) * 2 - 1;
  mouse.y = -(event.layerY / canvas.height) * 2 + 1;
  raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse.clone(), camera);
  let pos = raycaster.intersectObject(shapeMesh, true);
  //console.log(pos)
  if (pos[0]) {
    switch (type) {
      case 'mousedown':
        cons.innerHTML += "HIT!";
        shapeMesh.position.x = pos[0].point.x;
        shapeMesh.position.y = pos[0].point.y;
        break;
    }
  }

}
window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
  mouseController(e, 'mousedown')
}, false);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

canvas {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#console {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #666;
  height: 15px;
  width: 200px;
  z-index: 99;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: white;
  font-size: 9px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/110/three.min.js"></script>
<div id="console">

</div>
<canvas id="test"></canvas>
```

Any help will be great! Thanks again!

Comment: Can you put down a fiddle so we can see what is going wrong?

Comment: Hi! I've added a fiddle in the bottom of the post

Comment: I've added the fiddle just to further illustrate the point but the code in the question is the relevant part of the code in any case I'll add that to the question, no problem, can you help me if I do? @gman ?

Comment: I think you need to shift the origin of the square to the center so that when your mouse hits the area it's positioned from the centre.
I added Axes so you can see the original problem - https://jsfiddle.net/2xj8ak15/
Is this any closer to your desired outcome - https://jsfiddle.net/2xj8ak15/1/

Comment: Ohhhh it was so simple yet I haven't found that solution, thanks @danlong, if you can put it as an answer and I'll mark it as solved! Thanks again!!!

Comment: Glad that solved it for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The glitch you're seeing is becuase the centre of origin for the shape you've made it at the bottom left.

When you click with your mouse, the bottom left of the shape (it's centre of origin) is being positioned where the cursor clicks.

If you shift the centre of origin for the shape to it's 'actual' centre, when you click with your mouse the centre of the shape will be positioned at your mouse pointer.

There's lots of ways to do this, in this instance I used this code:

```
var center = new THREE.Vector3();
mesh.geometry.computeBoundingBox();
mesh.geometry.boundingBox.getCenter(center);
mesh.geometry.center();
mesh.position.copy(center);
```

from this post - https://discourse.threejs.org/t/geometry-center-will-change-the-location-of-mesh/4847 (thanks @prisoner849 again!)

Here's a jsfiddle of your code with the shape's centre of origin shifted - http://jsfiddle.net/2xj8ak15/1

Comment: Thanks a lot @danlong!